# UICollectionView Horizontal Scroll swiping left and right position of cell changes?

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

Horizontal Scroll in UICollectionView when i scroll left or right the cell not position right ? For each index item i can see the next item coming at the edge and scrolling further more of next cell is coming out to the current index. I want to show only the current index item in scroll. I dont know if its a layout issue ? Any help would be really helpfull. I set my collection view minimum spacing to 0.

[image]

Comment: collectionView.pagingEnabled = true

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code.also make sure to add UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: yourCollectionView.bounds.width, height: yourCollectionView.bounds.height)
    }
```